# Get User Android Version

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-2.3-gingerbread

is there any way for my application to get the user's Android Version or API Level ? .. because i am working on an app that supports API 9 (2.3 Gingerbread) .. and since API 9 does not support DialogFragments even with android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment imported, i decided to do an if else statement instead

if (the users Android Version is Lower than API 11)
{
 i will show a new class instead of a Dialog Fragment containing all information about the developer
}
else if (the users Android Version is Higher than or equal to API 11)
{
 my dialog fragment will show up containing all information about the developer
}

i hope anyone can help me out about this, thanks :)

Comment: Refer to `android.os.Build` class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) to get the API level. You can then compare it against values in `Build.VERSION_CODES`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  // do something cool
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard how to execute code for different versions.

Android provides a unique code for each platform version in the Build constants class. Use these codes within your app to build conditions that ensure the code that depends on higher API levels is executed only when those APIs are available on the system.

```
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    // We use the new method when supported
                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    // We check which build version we are using.
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            mapView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Build.VERSTION.RELEASE`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html